# Is this automatically added text, or are 10K users able to see flags for which a text has been provided?

Tags: support, moderator-tools, flag-reviews

One of the flagged posts shows the following text:

[image: screenshot]

Is it an automatically added text, or are 10k users able to see flags for which additional text has been provided?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an automatic flag by the [Community user](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community). Only diamond moderators can view flags which require the user to type in text.